# Need to throw an exception if a value is null and then continue the loop after the exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a list and list contains user name and mail address and some other details. So i want to loop through all the data and throw an exception if any value in the list has mail empty or null and then log that in the database and then continue the loop from there.

Currently my code is stopping when i am throwing an exception.

I have added an else statement where it checks if the user.mail is null then throw an exception which works but then after that the code breaks and the other item in the list doesnt get added to database.

```
foreach (var user in adUsers)
{
    if (!users.Keys.Contains(user.Mail) && user.Mail.EndsWith("@warburgpincus.com"))
        users.Add(user.Mail, new User
        {
            FirstName = user.GivenName,
            LastName = user.Surname,
            Username = user.UserPrincipalName,
            Email = user.Mail,
            IsActive = true,
            Role = adminMembers.Any() && adminMembers.Where(x => x.Mail == user.Mail).Any() ? RoleTypes.AdminUser :
            readOnlyMembers.Any() && readOnlyMembers.Where(x => x.Mail == user.Mail).Any() ? RoleTypes.ReadOnlyUser : RoleTypes.User
        });
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mail))                
    {            
        throw new ApplicationException($"User {user.GivenName + user.Surname} cannot sync to Quill due to missing email address");            
    }          
}
return users;
```

I want the error to be logged and then just return the user list and it should not break the look if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: @jdweng Oops sorry i missed that line. I have updated the code

Comment: There are a few mistakes in your snipped, but the question is why you want to throw an exception? Why not log directly into your database in the else block.

Comment: Stopping execution is kind of the point of exceptions. If all you want to do is skip the item and log the error, do that.

Comment: The code should stay in the loop if are getting into the ELSE. if the exception is occurring in the IF then you need to add a TRY/CATCH in the IF code.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception will automatically exit the function immediately.  If you want to log the error and continue, replace the code that throws the exception with the logging code.  If you need to know that an error occurred, you can always set a variable and raise the exception later, but multiple users might exist without email addresses. You can add the invalid users to a second list for reporting purposes depending on the context that you're calling the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside the for each loop inside a try catch. And then log the thrown exception inside catch. This won't break your loop.
Refer the below code:

```
 foreach (var user in adUsers)
{
    try{
        if (!users.Keys.Contains(user.Mail) && user.Mail.EndsWith("@warburgpincus.com"))
            users.Add(user.Mail, new User
            {
                FirstName = user.GivenName,
                LastName = user.Surname,
                Username = user.UserPrincipalName,
                Email = user.Mail,
                IsActive = true,
                Role = adminMembers.Any() && adminMembers.Where(x => x.Mail == user.Mail).Any() ? RoleTypes.AdminUser :
                readOnlyMembers.Any() && readOnlyMembers.Where(x => x.Mail == user.Mail).Any() ? RoleTypes.ReadOnlyUser : RoleTypes.User
            });

            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mail))        
            {

              throw new ApplicationException($"User {user.GivenName + user.Surname} cannot sync to Quill due to missing email address");
             }
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
        //log exception here.
     }

   }
 return users;
```